# memcached async calls in c++

Tags: c++, memcached

I have a question about libmemcached. Is there support for async calls?

What I'm trying to do is get values for some keys, but do further processing once I get the values back, in a callback.

I'm using libevent for my other async needs, if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Comment: [`MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_NO_BLOCK`](http://docs.libmemcached.org/memcached_behavior.html): Causes libmemcached(3) to use asychronous IO.

Comment: It's not at all evident how to use the flag from the docs. Could you provide an example of an async `get`? I'm also curious as to how it works :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Wajahat I can't be 100% sure as this was so long ago and I'm no longer involved with that project. But I'm 99% sure I haven't, otherwise I'd post something here. Sorry.